# How to make fail2ban block access to webpage on specific port

Tags: nginx, port, web, fail2ban

I am trying to deny access to all IPs except my own IP address. I think I could do this using Nginx log file, and create a filter and rule in fail2ban.

However, this specific page is on a port like the following and I have no control on changing the address (it is a software):

http://mywebsite.com:6900/software

accesses to this particular page is not listed on Nginx's access.log or error.log.

Excuse my incomplete knowledge, but I think to create a fail2ban rule, I need to have the log somewhere. If yes, how can I make Nginx to include the logs for this address.

PS: This particular software has a log file but does not log IP addresses.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to deny access to all IPs except my own IP address.

You can do this yourself with your firewall. For example

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp ! -s 192.0.2.2 --dport 6900 -j DROP
```

This will drop TCP connections for port 6900 if the source IP address is not 192.0.2.2 (your IP address).